# Ending Up With Same Value With STRPOS

Tags: php

strpos is returning the same value for all outcomes:

here is the code:

```
<?php
$test = strpos('{', $_GET['var1']) !== FALSE && strpos('}', $_GET['var1']) !== FALSE;

if( $test ) {
    $value = "yes";
}else{
    $value = "no";
}?>
<?php echo $value ?>
```

**URL1:** `http://example.com/test.php?var1=testingstrpos`

**URL2:** `http://example.com/test.php?var1=tes{tingst}rpos`

**URL3:** `http://example.com/test.php?var1=testingst}rpos`

**URL3:** `http://example.com/test.php?var1=te{stingstrpos`

URL1's Value should be `yes`, while URL2, URL3, and URL4 should be `no` since there is either `{`, `}`, or both `{` and `}` in the string. I'm currently getting the value `no` for everything.

How do I correct this?

Comment: You've confused the order of [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) arguments. The right order is: 1st - haystack (`$_GET['var1']`), 2nd - needle (search string)

Comment: @hindmost how did i?

Comment: We don't know *how* you did, but you did. The function signature is `strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
$test = !(strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== FALSE || strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== FALSE);
```

Comment: hello! I'm getting `no` for url1 and `yes` for the rest, what would be the best way to reverse it so I get `yes` for url1 and `no` for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

First parameter of `strpos` is full string and second parameter is searching string. Try this

```
$test = strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== false && strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== false;
if( $test ) {
    $value = "yes";
}else{
    $value = "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've confused the order of [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) arguments. The right order is:

1. **haystack** - the string to search in (`$_GET['var1']` in your case)
2. **needle** - the search string (`'{'` or `'}'`)

So the code should look like this:

```
$test = strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== false && strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== false;

$value = $test? "yes" : "no";

echo $value;
```